# requirejs: not loading libraries consistently on different sites

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Having some issues where I try to load store.js through require.js and the result is that it differs from site to site (I am trying to  a bookmarklet). I am using the list of sites from here. https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Sites-using-RequireJS.

bbc.com and fool.com works, but the other ones (http://www.rtt.ag/en, http://www.usatoday.com/, http://www.hallmark.com/easter/ideas/easter-recipes/) are inconsistent. For example, sometimes the jquery is unavailable, sometimes the qtip is unavailable, sometimes store is unavailable.

```
if (window.require) {
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            jq: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min',
            qtip2: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip',
            json2: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min',
            jstore: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/store.js/1.3.14/store.min'
        },
        map: {
            'qtip2': { 'jq': 'jquery-private' },
            'json2': { 'jq': 'jquery-private' }
        },
        findNestedDependencies: true
    });

    define('jquery-private', ['jq'], function () {
        return jQuery.noConflict(true);
    });

    require(['jstore'], function(store){
        require(['jquery-private', 'qtip2', 'json2'], function (jay) {
            console.log(store);
            console.log(jay);
            qtip2Initializer(jay,store);

        });
    });

}

function qtip2Initializer(jay,store) {
    console.log(jay().jquery);
    // Your logic to execute when qTip2 is available
    jay(document).ready(function () {
      $('a').qtip();
      store.set("test",1);
    });
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to a bookmarklet" What does this mean? You need to be more verbose about the context in which you are using RequireJS because it does not look to be a usual case. I use RequireJS for my applications and don't care one bit what goes on at bbc.com or fool.com.

Comment: "I am trying to make a bookmarklet", sorry I missed a word there, hope it makes sense now to you. It'd be helpful if you could highlight what  part of the question you are not clear with and I'll clarify that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's no mystery that your code is not working on some of those sites. I did not go down the *whole list* but http://www.rtt.ag/en and http://www.usatoday.com/ don't have `window.require` defined so the code you've shown would test for it, find it does not exist and skip the `if` branch. Here are some reasons why any given site might not work as you'd expect:

1. The list of sites you [refer to](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Sites-using-RequireJS) is community-maintained. So it can very well be wrong. If a site used to use RequireJS but don't any more, I don't expect their devs to run to this list and remove the link.
2. `window.require` could be defined for other reasons than RequireJS being loaded. Other loading systems define `require` in the global space. (You'd likely get some errors in the console.)
3. It is possible to use RequireJS and yet not have any of the symbols it normally defines in the global space be defined there. For instance, if the site uses an optimized bundle that uses the `namespace` option, the symbols that are normally global would instead be defined in this namespace.

   Another case is when the optimized bundle is loaded with [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) and configured to not leak anything into the global space.

Other problems with what you are trying to do:

1. `findNestedDependencies` is an optimizer option, not a runtime option. So it does nothing.
2. jQuery must be listed as `jquery` in dependencies because it hardcodes its name when it calls `define`. If you require it under a different name than `jquery` you get erratic behavior.
3. The intermittent errors you are reporting are typical for a situation in which jQuery is obtained from two different places. It could that in addition to your code loading jQuery with RequireJS:

   a. The site's code loads jQuery with RequireJS.

   b. The site's code loads jQuery with a `<script>` tag.

   c. The site's code loads jQuery in another way.

   Since RequireJS is asynchronous any code that depends on jQuery might get an instance of jQuery that is going to be overwritten when the second jQuery is loaded.

Comment: anyway to reliably inject my jquery plugins via requirejs? it seems one of the vars, `jay` or `store` becomes undefined in qtip2Initializer

Comment: I don't think there's a reliable way to do it the way you want to do it (with a bookmarklet) and have it work for a series of sites. At least, not without some major inspection of how each site works. I'm not familiar with browser extensions but this is what I would check to do what you want to do. I believe they are able to isolate the JavaScript that runs in the extension from the JavaScript that runs in the page.